# When I try to build the APK Following shows in the debug console. Build: Build Failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

When I try to build the APK Following shows in the debug console. Build: Build Failed with an exception .

Error in console :

> /C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.3.8/lib/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart:6:28:
> Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found. class DatePickerTheme
> with DiagnosticableMixin {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:26:
> Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found. class PictureStream with
> DiagnosticableMixin {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:44:
> Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found. abstract class
> PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.3.8/lib/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart:6:7:
> Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in. class
> DatePickerTheme with DiagnosticableMixin {
> ^ /C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:7:
> Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in. class
> PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
> ^ /C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16:
> Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in. abstract
> class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
> ^ /C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:167:11:
> Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
> super.debugFillProperties(properties);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:171:30:
> Error: The method 'toStringShort' isn't defined for the class
> 'PictureStreamCompleter'.
>
> - 'PictureStreamCompleter' is from 'package:flutter_svg/src/picture_stream.dart'
>   ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
>   a method named 'toStringShort'.
>   ifPresent: _completer?.toStringShort(),
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:266:11:
>   Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
>   super.debugFillProperties(description);
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle'
>   line: 896
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> > Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed
> with exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We can better assist you if provide the relevant code and explain your issue

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
dependency_overrides: flutter_svg: 0.18.0
```

in your pubspec.yaml

Comment: I am facing the same issue but there is no flutter_svg dependency i used in my project. Any other solution?

Comment: can you post your **pubspec.yaml** file here

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same error like you did and the solution for me was to update my flutter_svg packages to its latest version. So I recommand you to go into your pubspec.yaml and do following under dependencies:

```
flutter_svg: 0.18.0
```

Then run pub get and hopefully the error should disappear.

Answer (score 5):

```
To change dependency:

 flutter_svg: ^0.17.4  to flutter_svg: ^0.18.0
```

Then,

```
flutter pub get
flutter clean
```

Then, Run

Answer (score 3):

Try to write the package like this:

```
flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this is done the following updates in pubspec.yaml

```
Flutter_svg: ^0.18.0
flutter_html: ^1.0.2
flutter_widget_from_html: 0.4.3
```

Most errors by this three dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution go check [this](https://flutterhq.com/questions-and-answers/1513/flutter-compile-error-on-firebase-auth-a-non-null-value-must-be-returned-since-the-return-type-never-doesnt-allow-null) link. I upgraded the Flutter and dart to latest version, at the end I got a good result.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This solved the issue for me, use this `flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety` in your pubspec.yaml file dependency list.